# regression model selection method

Tags: regression, model-selection

Are there any academic papers that used **MSE*p** to select model from a set of candidate models (for example, candidate models are from backward selection)?

**MSE** is mean squared error, and **p** is the number of predictors in the regression model.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It sounds like you want to reward a model for achieving a small mean squared error but also penalize it for needing to use many parameters to do so. In that case, the standard metrics are adjusted $R^2$ and various forms of information criteria (Akaike, Bayesian, etc). Regarding your particular suggestion of $p\times MSE$, I have not seen that used.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I have used AIC, BIC and adjusted $R^2$, but they all failed to select the model that I wanted. And it is so weird that $p \times MSE$ could select the correct one. I am also looking for alternatives to solve my problem.

Comment: 1a) Why do you want to select a particular model? 1b) Why not just select that model? 2) In response to the last sentence of your comment, what problem are you trying to solve?